# Email VBA Excel - including range in email

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub sendEmail()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00"), "sendEmail"
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim rng As Range

EmailItem.To = "test@gmail.com"
EmailItem.CC = "test@yahoo.com"

EmailItem.Subject = "Update"

EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hi, Please see the below:"


Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:F22").SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible)

EmailItem.HTMLBody = RangeToHTML(rng)



EmailItem.Send

End Sub
```

This code isn't working - before I added in the part pulling the data it worked perfect, but as soon as I try and pull the range, nothing sends and I get a compile error 'sub or function not defined'.

Comment: What is `RangeToHTML`?

Comment: I guess you are missing the sub RangeToHtml from [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm). Other solution are available depending on what the data is.

Comment: As @CDP1802 mentioned, with 'sub or function not defined', vba saying "you are trying to call a sub or function, but I cannot find it (for some reason).  You need to add RangeToHtml function into your module.

Comment: I've just added in at the top below : Sub sendEmail() Sub RangeToHTML(rng As Range) and now I get the error 'Compile error: Expected End Sub'

Comment: Any thoughts? Sorry only just started learning VBA today.

Answer (score 0):

RangetoHMTL is a separate function by Ron de Bruin which you will need to include in order to copy your html range into your emails. Include the below code after End Sub in your code above or in a different module. Also read [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) for more information.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```